# Hibernate/JPA: Are nested flushes rolled back if @Transactional fails?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, rollback

Say I have method somewhere that's annotated `@Transactional` (thus starts a transaction) and inside do several `saveAndFlush()`. Maybe I even call some dependency that has a method that starts its own (sub? nested?) transaction by being annotated `@Transactional`. What gets rolled back if the transaction fails somewhere in between?

some example:

```
public class ComplexProcess {
    @Inject
    private DAO<SomeEntity> someEntityDao;

    @Inject
    private SomeManagerClass manager;

    @Transactional
    public void doStuff(SomeEntity entity) {
        manager.createAnObjectDependingOnEntity(entity);
        entity = someEntityDao.saveAndFlush(entity); // what if this fails?
        manager.doMoreStuffDependingOnEntity(entity);
    }
}

public class SomeManagerClass {

    @Inject
    private DAO<SomeObject> someObjectDao;

    @Inject
    private DAO<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntityDao;

    // what if this fails?
    @Transactional // what if this isn't there?
    public void createAnObjectDependingOnEntity(SomeEntity entity) {
        SomeObject someObject = createSomeObjectDependingOnEntity(entity);
        someObjectDao.saveAndFlush(someObject);
    }

    // what if this fails?
    @Transactional // what if this isn't there?
    public void doMoreStuffDependingOnEntity(SomeEntity entity) {
        SomeOtherEntity someOtherEntity = whatever(entity);
        someOtherEntityDao.safeAndFlush(someOtherEntity);
    }
}
```

Again: What if say the last step fails, will hibernate still rollback everything that happened before in `doStuff()`? Because I have a feeling it does not. If this complete rollback is impossible because of `saveAndFlush()`, will just using `save()` and waiting for the automatic flush at the end of the transaction help? I've just read that hibernate does some uncontrollable flushes on its own in between even before leaving the `@Transactional` block?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Flushing should not affect transaction management atl all. When transaction is rolled back, all changes made to the database state (i.e. changes flushed by Hibernate) inside that transaction are rolled back.
- Default propagation policy for `@Transactional` is `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`. It means that you can safely invoke `@Transactional` methods from other `@Transactional` methods, and they'll use the same transaction created by the top level transaction method. It's not so if you provide different propagation settings explicitly.

So, it means that any failure that happens during execution of the top level `@Transactional` method (i.e. any exception thrown from that method) should cause rollback, and all changes should be rolled back in this case.

If you observe different behavior, perhaps something is misconfigured (for example, the top level `@Transactional` doesn't take effect for some reason). Try to reproduce this behavior in tests.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear this.. ;) The problem with reproducing this in a test is our test setup that automatically creates a transaction for the entire test, preventing us from testing detachement issues by creating an object, ending the transaction and then starting a new transaction using that old object.. More TODOs.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

With your code all the changes Hibernate made should be rolled back, if somewhere it is decided to roll back the current transaction. Of course, only if everything is correctly configured.

Some common configuration problems are:
Your `persistence.xml` should define a `JTA` persistence unit (instead of a `RESOURCE_LOCAL`) and your database/tables should support transactions (e.g MySQL tables should be with the InnoDb search engine).